# HTML5 camera capture on Android WebView in Cordova Phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova, webview, phonegap-build

I have built a cordova phonegap application as a prototype.
Because it's a prototype I am basically just linking to a mobile webpage doing the following in the index.html:

```
<script>window.location = 'http://example.com';</script>
```

On example.com one crucial piece of html is this:

```
<input name="photo" id="upload-image" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" >
```

In the compiled phonegap app which I compile via build.phonegap.com, after downloading and running the .apk file on Android, when clicking on that file control it only opens the local file browser without camera option.

Is there a way to make this work so that it offers to launch the camera or ideally just directly launches the camera?

When I access the mobile site via Chrome from an Android it works as expected, but when running the compiled apk it seems to be using a different browser that doesn't seem to interpret the tag and its attributes as expected.

Comment: Is it a `cordova` application or you are calling `url` in webview ?

Comment: Did you add camera permission in your cordova app manifest?

Comment: I'm calling the URL in webview (inside a cordova application though).

Comment: No I did not add camera permission in my cordova app manifest. How do I do that?

Comment: You have to add to AndroidManifest.xml this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`.

Comment: Thanks, where is the AndroidManifest.xml file? I see a config.xml ...

Comment: So I've now added the following to the config.xml file, which as far as I could find is the way to add camera permissions in phonegap build:

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>

However, the behavior of the file selector doesn't change.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: input type file is implemented in this way on cordova apps, you can't change that behaviour

Comment: Make sure you use https too

Comment: did you find the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't support accept attributes in webview.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept&search=Accept

Consider using Cordova Camera plugin

Answer (score 0):

***It is possible***

Add crosswalk pluggin (will replace webview)

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html

And add camera plugin.

Then add this code to **onDeviceReady** function (Just for gettiing premissions)

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });

        function onSuccess(imageURI) {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            image.src = imageURI;
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
```

Now This should open device camera

```
<input name="photo" id="upload-image" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" >
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it all wrong. As is a phonegap application you need to implement the camera plugin to use the camera functionality.

Follow the instruction in the following link and you will be able to use the camera in your app.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html